# Dynamically changing cursor size with custom cursor image in javascript without canvas

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I'd like to use a custom image as my cursor over a certain div but change its size dynamically .  I would need a wide range of sizes so having a bunch of different images for each size would be a bear.  Is there an easy way so scale the image the is associated with the cursor using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

with the height and weight set in the CSS, you can easily just scale the image with jquery/javascript. just use an onMouseOver event and set the css. Here's a little more info: http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-image-cursors.html